# How to set the label for listings?

Tags: listings, tcolorbox, minted

Hi I'm new in Latex and I'm using this code from the Board everything is working, but I don't know how to set the label for the listing with this code

```
\usepackage[many,minted]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\mynewminted}[3]{%
  \newminted[#1]{#2}{#3}%
  \tcbset{myminted/#1/.style={minted language=#2,minted options={#3}}}}

\mynewminted{myc}{c}{tabsize=2,fontsize=\footnotesize,linenos, numbersep=3mm}

\newtcblisting[auto counter,number within=section,
  list inside=mypyg]{listingsbox}[3][]{%
  listing only,
  title={Listing \thetcbcounter: #3},
  list entry={\protect\numberline{\thetcbcounter}#3},
  enhanced,
  left=6mm,
  overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[black!15] (frame.south west)
            rectangle ([xshift=6mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}},
  colframe=black!35,
  drop fuzzy shadow,
  myminted/#2,#1}


\begin{listingsbox}{myc}{test} 

Examplecode

\end{listingsbox}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is easier to help you if you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to troubleshoot your problem - and much more likely that they will!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want to `\label` the listing and `\ref` it somewhere. If so, add the label like:

```
\begin{listingsbox}{myc,label=mint}{test}
```

and use `\ref{mint}` elsewhere.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many,minted]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\mynewminted}[3]{%
  \newminted[#1]{#2}{#3}%
  \tcbset{myminted/#1/.style={minted language=#2,minted options={#3}}}}

\mynewminted{myc}{c}{tabsize=2,fontsize=\footnotesize,linenos, numbersep=3mm}

\newtcblisting[auto counter,number within=section,
  list inside=mypyg]{listingsbox}[3][]{%
  listing only,
  title={Listing \thetcbcounter: #3},
  list entry={\protect\numberline{\thetcbcounter}#3},
  enhanced,
  left=6mm,
  overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[black!15] (frame.south west)
            rectangle ([xshift=6mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}},
  colframe=black!35,
  drop fuzzy shadow,
  myminted/#2,#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{listingsbox}{myc,label=mint}{test}

Examplecode

\end{listingsbox}

From listing~\ref{mint}, we see a code.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If my understanding is wrong, let me know.

Comment: That`s it! Thank you very much for your quick help.

Comment: @henry If Harish's answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Hi, now i have a new problem :-), how can i set the line spacing in the tcbbox?

Comment: @henry This should be asked a new question certainly. Load `\usepackage{setspace}` and put `before upper = \setstretch{1.5}` in the options.